# Firefox extension launch website in new tab

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to launch a webpage on first install of my firefox extension.

Can anyone point me to some documentation on to how to do this?

Regards,
Ash

Answer (score 3):

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978188/how-do-i-detect-a-first-run-in-firefox-a-addon) on how to detect a first run, and [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) on how to open a tab.